# match objects then calculate grade for student grade

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

I'm stuck with a problem.

So i'm making this student grading system. The way it works is that the system should be able to match answer key with a student's answer. The answer keys are stored like this:

```
 const answerkeys = {math01: a, math02: b, math03 : d, ...}
```

There is also a grading system where math01 is worth 5 points, and math 02 worth 10 points, etc. Out of confusion, i saved the data in another set of data collection as something like this:

```
const scoring = {math01: 5, math02: 10, math03: 5, ...}
```

And then the students' answers are stored like this:

```
const answers = {0: {math01: a, math02: c, ... }
           1: {math01: b, math02: a, ... }
           2: {math01: a, math02: c, ... }
           ...
           }
```

At first, logically i thought i can iterate answers, then the individual result will be matched with answerkeys and the returned (matches) will then be multiplied with answerkeyandscore.

So i tried doing it this way:

```
const studentAnswers = answers.map((elem) => {return elem});

studentAnswer.filter(answer => answerkeys.includes(answer));
```

But it is giving me

> "result.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'filter')"

How to compare between "answerkeys" and "answers" and then calculate the scores using "scoring"?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native `map` to the `Object` object, but i suggest this will works:

```
let allStudentsScores = {}

for (var idx in answers) {
    let studentAnswer = answers[idx]
    let studentScore = 0
    for(var key in studentAnswer) {
        if (studentAnswer[key]==answerkeys[key]) {
            studentScore += scoring[key]
        }

    }
    allStudentsScores[idx] = studentScore
}
```

the `allStudentsScores` variable contains each of student's score. Where the `idx <0, 1, 2, ...>` represents each student.

Hope answers your question.